# Javascript update array when condition is met otherwise add new record to the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have one array `userRoleArray` like:

```
[
    {
        userId: 1,
        userRoles: [
            { userRoleId: 1, roleName: "A" },
            { userRoleId: 2, roleName: "B" }
        ]
    },
    {
        userId: 2,
        userRoles: [
            { userRoleId: 2, roleName: "B" },
            { userRoleId: 3, roleName: "C" }
        ]
    }
]
```

What I'm trying to do is by given the target `userId` and new `userRoles`, if I can find the `userId`, I will add the new `userRoles`, otherwise, if there is no `userId` found, I will add the new record to the array.

This is what I tried:

```
const findStatus = userRoleArray.find((item) => {
    return item.userId === userId
})
if (!findStatus) {
    // new record
    userRoleArray.push({ userId, userRoles })
} else {
    // update existing record
    userRoleArray = userRoleArray.map((item) => {
        if (item.userId === userId) {
            // update found record
            return { ...item, userId, userRoles: [...item.userRoles, { ...userRoles }] }
        }
        return item
    })
}
```

when

```
const userId = 2
const userRoles = { userRoleId: 4, roleName: "D" }
```

a new record added to `userId` equal 2.

If

```
const userId = 4
const userRoles = { userRoleId: 4, roleName: "D" }
```

a new record added to the `userRoleArray` array.

Is there a way I can combine the array find method and array map method together?

**Edit**: I will use this on Redux reducer, so the array should be immutable.

Comment: For clarification, do you need to not mutate the objects? Or can you just edit the role directly? As in, instead of doing the whole map thing, could you just do `findStatus.userRoles = [...]`?

Comment: Yes, immutable. This is for Redux reducer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `findIndex` instead of `find`. `findIndex` will give the index of the object if they matches where as `find` will give the object. So on using `findIndex` get the index of the matched object. If it is -1 then the object does not exist and you can add new object , if it is not `-1` then get the object and update userRoles

```js
let userRoleArray = [{
    userId: 1,
    userRoles: [{
        userRoleId: 1,
        roleName: "A"
      },
      {
        userRoleId: 2,
        roleName: "B"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    userId: 2,
    userRoles: [{
        userRoleId: 2,
        roleName: "B"
      },
      {
        userRoleId: 3,
        roleName: "C"
      }
    ]
  }
];

function updateArray(userId, userRoles) {
  const findStatus = userRoleArray.findIndex(item => {
    return item.userId === userId;
  });
  if (findStatus === -1) {
    userRoleArray.push({
      userId,
      userRoles
    });
  }

  if (!findStatus) {
    // new record
    userRoleArray.push({
      userId,
      userRoles
    });
  } else {}
}

updateArray(4, {
  userRoleId: 4,
  roleName: "D"
});
console.log("Adding new userId", userRoleArray);
updateArray(2, {
  userRoleId: 4,
  roleName: "D"
});
console.log("Updating old record ", userRoleArray);
```